# Xpath child of multiple types

Tags: xpath

I have this xpath:

```
.//*[@id='some_id']/td//div
```

and now I want to select any child of the div that is of certain type, for example every child that is either a label or span. Something like this

```
.//*[@id='some_id']/td//div/(label|span)/.......
```

but that is not valid xpath. How can I do that (wthout writing two full xpaths for the given 2 example for child types)

Comment: `.//*[@id='some_id']/td//div/*[self::label or self::span]`

Comment: The path you have given (`td/div/(label|span)`) is valid in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0. Please tag your questions "XPath 1.0" if you are only interested in 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use

> descendant::

to select child elements of particular element. look at the below example,

```
.//*[@id='some_id']/td//div/descendant::label[@class='some-class']
```

the above xpath will get all label with class "some-class" which is actually the child of ".//*[@id='some_id']/td//div/" element.

to find multiple child elements then use below xpath,

```
.//*[@id='some_id']/td//div/descendant::*[local-name()='label' or local-name='span']
```

Comment: descendant:: covers both children, grandchildren and all other descendants, not just children. The result might have unwanted tags.

Answer (score 6):

`descendant::` finds on all level below, to find only children use

```
.//*[@id='some_id']/td//div/*[self::label or self::span]
```